# Is there a convex function satisfying certain growth and smothness conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, interpolation, spline

I would like find (if it exists) a function $F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that the following conditions hold true:

1. $F\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$
2. $F$ is radial, that is $F(x,y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,)$
3. $f$ is strongly convex on $[0,\infty)$ (i.e., $\min_{r\geq0} f''(r)>0)$
4. $\min_{r\geq0} f(r)=f(1)=0$
5. $\lim_{r\to\infty}f(r)/r^4\in(0,\infty)$

For example $f(r)\equiv(r^2-1)^2$ gives $F(x,y)=(x^2+y^2-1)^2$ and conditions 1., 2., 4., 5. are satisfied but convexity is not, since $f$ has an inflection point at $r_0\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Is it possible to modify $f$ in order to satisfy all the conditions 1.-5. ?

[image]

Notice that if $f$ is polynomial with odd power terms, condition 1. is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an $F$ doesn't exist:

Conditions 1 and 2 imply $x \mapsto f(\vert x\vert)$ is differentiable at $0$, and then

$$\lim_{x \uparrow0}\frac{f(\vert x\vert)-f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \uparrow0}\frac{f(-x)-f(0)}{x} =  \lim_{h \downarrow0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{-h} = -\lim_{h \downarrow0}\frac{f(\vert h \vert)-f(0)}{h}$$

shows that the derivative must be $0$, which also implies $f'(0) = 0$.

But condition 4 implies $f'(1) = 0$, so Rolle's theorem gives us a point in $(0, 1)$ where the second derivative vanishes, contradicting condition 3.